# Where are saved logs about Rails app in production if error 500?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging, unicorn, production

I installed a Rails app on the DigitalOcean server, but instead of seeing the app itself, there's the error 500 page.

When I check the directory "logs", there are no data written in the production.log file, or in the unicorn.log.

So, how can I find out what's wrong?

Comment: Does it run passenger?

Comment: No, nginx, capistrano,

Comment: Try ps -eaf and look for nginx.  You might see the log dir as an argument to the process.

Comment: I see there's "/usr/sbin/nginx", but that's a runable file, not a log file.

Answer (score 1):

You could try look for nginx's logs in:

/var/log/nginx

usually are placed there:
access.log and error.log